# Where do i get the api for the linux kernel that would let me access information within the kernel

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel, kernel

I am new to Linux,  After implementing a simple system call on the Linux kernel that prints to the syslog via printk,

I would like to be able to extend this application , so I can get details on the battery percentage of my laptop or check the speed of the hard drive in the computer, could any of you give me a hand on where i would get the code that would help me access this type of information within my kernel,

(I have no idea how I found printk, and I have no idea where i could get further information on printk)

also if guys could provide a simple but useful system call that I could implement myself that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a good starting point for you to learn about making system calls to the kernel. This cheatsheet also has a sample C code.

Download it [here](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/LINUX%20System%20Call%20Quick%20Reference.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: i need to be able get information within a systemcall of my own in the kernel, and then call that new system call. it should allow a non root user to call systemcalls

Answer (score 0):

Check out /proc and /sys on your filesystem; between the two, you should be able to find everything you need without system calls.

For example:

- What is my CPU speed? Check `/proc/cpuinfo`
- How much RAM do I have? Check `/proc/meminfo`
- What size is `/dev/sda`? Check `/sys/block/sda/size`

Some things I'm not sure how to test (for example, the two things you asked about), but you may be able to find them with a little digging.

If you're really curious how stuff works, check out the source for the drivers for the devices you are interested in; they provide those filesystem entries, so they should (hopefully) document what is in each.

Comment: in the folders now, they arnt telling me much

Comment: but this is a homework assignment, and i need to be able to be able to give not normally avialable kernel information to the user(demonstrate capability for new system call not normally available to a non-root user)

Comment: Ohhhh... Perhaps you'd have better luck looking at the scheduler, then. Generally there isn't much output from that, since it needs to be so efficient, but you could add some instrumentation to count, say, context switches, processor affinity, ...

Comment: now, how would i go about looking at code(documentation) that would give me access to the scheduler

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with it myself, as the system calls I added for a research project were like five years ago, but take a look at Con Kolivas's BFS patch. That should tell you where to look for scheduler stuff. http://ck.kolivas.org/patches/bfs/